# How to get JSON objects in Unity using REST

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, proyecto26.restclient

I have been troubleshooting for awhile and have no success in getting the correct response for my unity application. The login post from client to server is successful its just that the response I expected was not the correct one to my unity. Kindly check my code below.

**This is the model class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Models
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Post
    {
        public string identifier;
        public string password;
        public string jwt;
        public string user;
        public override string ToString(){
            return UnityEngine.JsonUtility.ToJson (this, true);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my post request**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using Models;
using Proyecto26;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

using SimpleJSON;

public class MainScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private readonly string basePath = "http://localhost:1337";
    private RequestHelper currentRequest;
    public InputField username;
    public InputField password;


    private void LogMessage(string title, string message) {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        EditorUtility.DisplayDialog (title, message, "Ok");
#else
        Debug.Log(message);
#endif
public void Post(){

        Debug.Log(username.text);
        Debug.Log(password.text);
        currentRequest = new RequestHelper {
            Uri = basePath + "/auth/local",
            Body = new Post {
                 identifier ="gofor+bs@gmail.com",
                 password ="12345678"
            }
        };
        RestClient.Post<Post>(currentRequest)
        .Then(
            res => {
                EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("JSON", JsonUtility.ToJson(res, true), "Ok");
                Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(res, true));
            }
            // this.LogMessage("Success",  )
            )
        .Catch(err => this.LogMessage("Error", err.Message));
    }
    }
```

**This is the response from POSTMAN after successful authentication/login.**

```
{
    "jwt": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZDgxOWI5ZWVmYWY3ZDE0MjRhMGNlM2UiLCJpZCI6IjVkODE5YjllZWZhZjdkMTQyNGEwY2UzZSIsImlhdCI6MTU2ODc3NTYzMywiZXhwIjoxNTcxMzY3NjMzfQ.-v33TvKW2pLuLU-w596bzXAamC0Wecpfrv3pOPsB_bI",
    "user": {
        "_id": "5d819b9eefaf7d1424a0ce3e",
        "confirmed": true,
        "blocked": false,
        "email": "gofor+bs@gmail.com",
        "username": "user1",
        "provider": "local",
        "__v": 0,
        "id": "5d819b9eefaf7d1424a0ce3e",
        "role": {
            "_id": "5d8040be9a4f6d25281e8097",
            "name": "Authenticated",
            "description": "Default role given to authenticated user.",
            "type": "authenticated",
            "__v": 0
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the response I got**

The user object is what I need but here it is empty.

```
{
    "identifier": "",
    "password": "",
    "jwt": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZDgxOWI5ZWVmYWY3ZDE0MjRhMGNlM2UiLCJpZCI6IjVkODE5YjllZWZhZjdkMTQyNGEwY2UzZSIsImlhdCI6MTU2ODc3ODY1MCwiZXhwIjoxNTcxMzcwNjUwfQ.vCC_EwyH5iAUT6y83PuF92F7Xok4cGhdlkSU7Y0kYqE",
    "user": ""
}
```

How should i get the "user" string/object? I am still new to C# and Unity so I need some expert advice on what to do here. I Appreciate your help guys. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `user` isn't a string but a complex type ....

Comment: Is there a way i can get those complex type?

Comment: Unity has a built-in method to parse Json data : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `user` isn't a simple `string` but a complex type with even one more subtype `role`.

In order to get these your c# data structure has to mirror exactly the JSON structure.

Simplest way for start: pass your json in to [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

and modify the result slightly to make it work with unity:

```
[Serializable]
public class Role
{
    public string _id;
    public string name;
    public string description;
    public string type;
    public int __v;
}

[Serializable]
public class User
{
    public string _id;
    public bool confirmed;
    public bool blocked;
    public string email;
    public string username;
    public string provider;
    public int __v;
    public string id;
    public Role role;
}

[Serializable]
public class Post
{
    // use NonSerialized to avoid these being printed to the json
    [System.NonSerialized] public string identifier;
    [System.NonSerialized] public string password;

    public string jwt;
    public User user;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return UnityEngine.JsonUtility.ToJson (this, true);
    }
}
```

The class names can be called whatever you like btw since Json doesn't care.

---

Also note that in general this is quite redundant

```
EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("JSON", JsonUtility.ToJson(res, true), "Ok");
Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(res, true));
```

if it all was only about displaying the json you might rather want to use [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) instead of Unity's `JsonUtility` and could simply do ([source](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/mar/31/prettifying-a-json-string-in-net))

```
string jsonFormatted = JValue.Parse(res).ToString(Formatting.Indented);

EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("JSON", jsonFormatted, "Ok");
Debug.Log(jsonFormatted);
```

without even having to care about the c# data structure at all.

Comment: Thank you brother everything works! but that I have another question. If in User model there is another field that is an array how do I deal with that? Here is what I did. So basically i want to get the array objects in {"kids": [{name:"kid1"}, {name:"kid2"}] } I created another model for it but it does not work. Kindly view my code here: repl.it/@Jerson_AndyAndy/CUserModel – andymyst

Comment: @andymyst as said the c# strcuture has to mirror **exactly** the JSON structure most importantly with matching field names. in your JSON the `Kid` class has a field `name` .. (note btw that this is not correct JSON! The field names have to be wrapped in `"` so it should rather be `{"kids": [{"name":"kid1"}, {"name":"kid2"}] }`) in your c# code however you only have the fields `firstname` and `lastname` but none for `name`

Comment: Thanks for the response. actually I generated it on JSON2charp. I have updated my code on the link I gave you. Also here is a very short screenscast for on the unity3d app i am building that has problem on kids array [link]https://www.screencast.com/t/ukg1amQpl I badly need help with this :-( this is my first Unity app that involves json. Thank you for answering brother!

Comment: well .. it seems that it has nothing to do with your class but the server or wherever you get this JSON from simply sends you an empty array. (for markdown link formatting is like `[label](url)` btw ;) )

Comment: hahaha sorry this is all very new to me :-)  I will look into it. Seems there is a restriction on the api I am connecting to. Again, Thank you helping :-)